# Proving limit of sequence equals $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, lebesgue-integral

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be integrable and $a>0$.

I would like to prove that

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(nx) / n^{-a} = 0$ for almost all $x \in \mathbb R$.

We already proved that for almost all $x \in \mathbb R$ the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} f(n+x/a)$ converges and that

$\int_0^a g(x) dx = a \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$ holds where

$g(x) := \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} f(n+x/a)$, if the series converges, and $0$ else.

Does anybody have an idea how to do that? (I am not sure if the last two statements could be useful)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The idea is the same: Show that $h(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(nx)|n^{-a}$ is finite a.e. by showing that $\int_{\Bbb R} hx)\,dx<\infty$.

Comment: 3rd line ought to be $f(nx)n^{-a}$; otherwise $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}, a=2$ gives a contradiction.